# Xamarin Essentials Secure Storage - possible to require user authentication?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

I have a Xamarin Forms 5 application for Android and iOS.

I use the great Xamarin Essentials Secure Storage which easy to use. It utilizes the platform specific way of storing resources securely - Android: Keystore / shared preferences, iOS: Keychain.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage

On both native Android and iOS you can specify that a resource can only be access if the user is authenticated by the device (pincode/biometri). I.e. if the user does not have any device-lock on the device, the resource cannot be accessed. I can also see, that it is possible through Xamarin.iOS to set an accessible enum to specify this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/security.secaccessible?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12

But I cannot find any handles inside Xamarin Essentials Secure Storage to specify whether a resource can be accessed with authentication only. Am I missing something, or is this not possible in Xamarin without doing platform specific implementations manually?

My dream scenario would be something like this

```
try
{
  await SecureStorage.SetAsync("oauth_token", "secret-oauth-token-value", SecAccessible.WhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // Possible that device doesn't support secure storage on device.
}
```

Comment: What you are looking for is a custom scenario and has nothing to do with secure storage you will have to implement it yourself

Comment: As @FreakyAli says, you would want to implement custom logic where you first check authentication, then go to secure storage.